# How do I manage a JavaScript library with TFS?

Tags: javascript, libraries, code-reuse, team-foundation-server

I know that I can share files between Visual Studio projects using linked files and assemblies using project references. Is there a good approach for JavaScripts? I'd rather not use linked files since it doesn't allow projects to have their own version of the script.

Comment: Isn't a Javascript script just another source file in VS?